# Upload multiple attachment at once in Odoo 9

Tags: javascript, widget, multi-select, odoo-9, qweb

I'm trying to make a feature in Odoo that allows a user to upload multiple files from an attachment form, and when he submits it, it creates as many attachments as selected documents.

I created a widget for the 'binary' field that allows the multi selection (Adding 'multiple' argument to 'input' tag in a Qweb template), but at this point i'm struggling with attachments creation and linking them with the concerned field from JS.

my widget :

```
odoo.define('lettermgmt', function(require)
{
    'use strict';
    var core = require('web.core');
    var FieldBinaryFile = core.form_widget_registry.get('binary');
    var FieldBinaryMultipleFiles = FieldBinaryFile.extend({
        template : 'FieldBinaryMultipleFiles',
    });
    core.form_widget_registry.add('binary_multiple_files',FieldBinaryMultipleFiles);

});
```

My first guess was to override `on_file_change` method, loop over "`e.target.files`" and make a POST request for each file on '`/web/binary/upload_attachment`'. this creates the attachments but i couldn't figure out how to link them to my model (relational field).

I'll appreciate any help :)

Comment: Are you setting both `res_model` and `res_id` fields on the `ir.attachment` records that you are creating? Those tell Odoo which record to display the attachment on.

Comment: Also, I would highly suggest you add that multiple upload functionality to Github or Odoo apps or something. It is something I would love to use and I'm sure many others.

Comment: Hi trasvisw,
I'm setting the res_model but not the res_id which i can't get on record creation.
Once done i'll upload it on Github ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution :

The idea is to create a custom char widget with specific behavior.
JS Code here :

```
odoo.define('cutom_module', function(require)
{
    'use strict';
    var core = require('web.core');
    var Char = core.form_widget_registry.get('char');

    var import_button = Char.extend({
       template : "import_button",
        events : {
           'change' : 'import_files',
        },
        init : function(){
           this._super.apply(this,arguments);
           this._start = null;
        },
        start : function() {
        },
        import_files : function(event){
            var self = this;
            var files = event.target.files; // Get Selected files
            var attachment_ids = self.getParent().fields[ 'attachment_ids' ]; // Get existing attachments
            var data64 = null;
            var values_list = [];
            _.each(files, function(file){
                // Check if the file is already in the attachments, must specify field name here :/
                if(self.already_attached(attachment_ids.get_value(),file.name)){
                    return;
                }
                var filereader = new FileReader();
                filereader.readAsDataURL(file);
                filereader.onloadend = function(upload) {
                        var data = upload.target.result;
                        data64 = data.split(',')[1];
                        var values = {
                            'name' : file.name,
                            'type' : 'binary',
                            'datas' : data64,
                        };
                        values_list.push([ 0, 0, values]);
                        if(values_list.length == files.length){
                            attachment_ids.set_value(values_list);
                        }
                };
            });
        },
        already_attached : function (attachments,filename) {
              for(var i=0;i<attachments.length;i++){
                  if(attachments[i][2]['name'] == filename){
                      return true;
                  }
              }
              return false;
        },
    });

    core.form_widget_registry.add('import_button',import_button);

});
```

Qweb for import_button template :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="HiddenInputMultipleFiles">
        <div t-attf-class="oe_hidden_input_file #{fileupload_class or ''}" t-att-style="fileupload_style">
            <form class="o_form_binary_form" t-att-target="fileupload_id"
                  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" t-att-action="'/web/binary/upload_attachment'">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="csrf_token"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="" t-if="widget.session.override_session"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="callback" t-att-value="fileupload_id"/>
                <t t-raw="0"/>
                <input type="file" class="o_form_input_file" name="ufile" t-if="widget.widget!='image'" multiple="multiple"/>
                <input type="file" class="o_form_input_file" name="ufile" accept="image/*" t-if="widget.widget=='image'"/>
            </form>
            <iframe t-att-id="fileupload_id" t-att-name="fileupload_id" style="display: none"/>
        </div>
    </t>

    <div  t-name="import_button" t-attf-class="base #{cls}" class="oe_web_example">
        <p>
            <t t-call="HiddenInputMultipleFiles">

            </t>
        </p>
    </div>
</templates>
```

View :

```
....
<field name="import_files" widget="import_button"/>
<field name="attachment_ids" widget="one2many_list"
                        >
                            <tree create="0">
                                <field name="name" string="File name"/>
                            </tree>
                    </field>
....
```

and the model :

```
....
attachment_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="ir.attachment",string="Documents")
import_files = fields.Char(string=" ")
....
```

If you have questions or suggestions for improvements let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

What also seems to work is to let the default submit handle 1 file and the custom code for the extra files.

```
openerp.web_natuurpunt_multi_attach = function (session) {
var QWeb = session.web.qweb;
var _t  = session.web._t;

session.web.Sidebar.include({

    on_attachment_changed: function (event) {
        var self = this;
        var session_id = this.session.session_id
        this.$el.find('form.oe_form_binary_form').bind('submit', function (e, data) {
             var form = e.currentTarget;
             var multipleFiles = form.querySelector('input[type=file]');

             if (multipleFiles.files.length > 1) {
                 var callback = form.querySelector('input[name=callback]').defaultValue;
                 var model = form.querySelector('input[name=model]').defaultValue;
                 var id = form.querySelector('input[name=id]').defaultValue
                 const slicedFileList = Object.keys(multipleFiles.files)
                                        .slice(0,multipleFiles.files.length - 1)
                                        .reduce((result, key) => {
                                            result[key] = multipleFiles.files[key];
                                            return result;
                                        }, {});

                 _.each(slicedFileList, function(file){
                     var queryData = new FormData();
                     queryData.append('session_id', session_id);
                     queryData.append('callback', callback);
                     queryData.append('ufile', file);
                     queryData.append('model', model);
                     queryData.append('id', id);
                     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                     // do the request using form info
                     request.open(form.method, form.action);
                     // want to distinguish from non-JS submits?
                     request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                     request.send(queryData);
                 });
             }
        });
        self._super(event);
    },
});
}
```